# JFrame's Oval is being placed behind the Rectangles JAVA

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, rectangles

So, I'm building a Tic Tac Toe game for my Computer Programming topic. My problem is when I add an Oval to my JFrame, it gets placed behind my tiles of the game board (They're Rectangles).

(Mind you i've added an extra parameter to the Rectangle and Oval to choose the color of it).

So my Questions:
Is there an easy way to change an objects color?
How can I place the Ovals on top of the Rectangles?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GameBoard{
   static JFrame f = new JFrame("Tic Tac Toe");
   static JPanel win = new JPanel();
   static Rectangle re[][] = new Rectangle[3][3];

   static Oval player1[][] = new Oval[9][9];
   static Oval player2[][] = new Oval[9][9];  

   public static void main(String args[]){
      f.setBounds(50, 50, 256, 279);
      f.setLayout(null);
      f.setVisible(true);
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


      win.add(new Rectangle(0,0,80,80,1));
      win.add(new Rectangle(81,0,80,80,0));     
      win.add(new Rectangle(162,0,80,80,1));

      win.add(new Rectangle(0,81,80,80,0));
      win.add(new Rectangle(81,81,80,80,1));
      win.add(new Rectangle(162,81,80,80,0));

      win.add(new Rectangle(0,162,80,80,1));
      win.add(new Rectangle(81,162,80,80,0));
      win.add(new Rectangle(162,162,80,80,1));
      f.getContentPane().add(win);
      f.repaint();

      userInput();

   }   

   static int p1Count = 0;
   static int p2Count = 0;

   static void userInput(){
      int uImpCalc = 1; 
      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
      while(uImpCalc <= 9){

         int x = s.nextInt();
         int y = s.nextInt();
         if(x <= 3 && x > 0){
            if(y <= 3 && y >0){
               int rX = x*80;
               int rY = y*80;
               if(uImpCalc%2 == 0){
                  player1[p1Count][p1Count] = new Oval(rY, rX, 80, 80, 2); 
                  win.add(player1[p1Count][p1Count]);
                  p1Count++;
               }else{
                  player2[p2Count][p2Count] = new Oval(rY, rX, 80, 80, 1); 
                  win.add(player2[p2Count][p2Count]);
                  p2Count++;
               }
               win.repaint();

               System.out.println("Entering '"+x+", "+y+"'");
               uImpCalc++;

            }else{
               System.out.println("Invalid Y: "+y);
            }

         }else{
            System.out.println("Invalid X: "+x);
         }

      }
     System.out.println("Game Over");
      System.exit(0); 
   }
}
```

Much appreciated!

Comment: You could have created a matrix of button or label and when a user clicks on them add a image of cross or oval depending on the user.

Comment: Thanks mate, however i'm asked to input a co-ordinate i.e "1 1" and place a green or blue oval in the rectangle with that co-ordinate